# ActionController::UrlGenerationError no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am still very much new to rails, but cant seem to get a grasp on this route

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "up", vote_movie_review_path(@review, type: "up"), method: "post" %>
```

**rake route**

```
vote_movie_review POST   /movies/:movie_id/reviews/:id/vote(.:format) reviews#vote
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

devise_for :users
resources :movies do 
  resources :reviews  do 
  member { post :vote }
  end
end
```

**reviews_controller.rb**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_reviews, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :set_movie
before_action :authenticate_user!
respond_to :html

def index
  @reviews = Review.all
  respond_with(@reviews)
end

def show

end

def vote
  value - params[:type] == "up" ? 1 : -1
  @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  @review.add_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
  redirect_to :back, notice: "thanks for the vote"
end
```

Comment: Post the full error please and stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using nested routes, so you need to pass movie object also.use like this `vote_movie_review_path(@movies, @review, type: "up")`.

Check your routes, it showing `/movies/:movie_id/reviews/:id/vote` while the way you are calling it will generate like `/reviews/id` with method post and for it you have not defined any routes.